# Select units with observations in multiple time indicators

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

````
```
idpers <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5)
wave <- c(2008,2009,2012,2008,2011,2005,2006,2007,2008, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011)
df.short <-  as.data.frame(idpers,wave)
```
````

Which is based on multiple waves of a panel survey (same people (idpers) interviewed at different years (wave)). What I am trying to do is to keep only people who are both before (2005-08) AND after the year of 2009 (2010-15), but doesn't really matter which years.

So basically something like this:

````
```
idpers <- c(1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4)
wave <- c(2008,2009,2012,2008,2011,2008, 2009, 2010)
df.desired <- as.data.frame(idpers, wave)
```
````

I tried different things, like:

````
```
Keep only those in waves pre and post?
df %>%
  group_by(idpers)%>%
  select(wave %in% c(2005|2006|2007|2008) & wave %in% c(2010|2011|2012))

#and get the following:
Error in select(., wave %in% c(2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008) & wave %in% : unused argument (wave %in% c(2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008) & wave %in% c(2010 | 2011 | 2012))
```
````

All help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have also gone with `any(.)` combined with a `filter`-verb as Matt did. You can skip the mutating and filter though, not sure how data we're talking but it could be costly, creating `pre` and `post` just for selecting them out a second later and creating a boolean from an already boolean vector with ifelse. Or am I missing something? :)

```
df.short<-structure(list(idpers=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,
5),wave=c(2008,2009,2012,2008,2011,2005,2006,2007,
2008,2008,2009,2010,2011)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,
-13L))

df.short %>% 
  group_by(idpers) %>%
  filter(any(wave %in% 2005:2008) & any(wave %in% 2010:2012))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you can do:

```
df.short %>% 
  group_by(idpers) %>% 
  filter(any(wave <= 2008)) & any(wave >= 2010))
```

Which gives us:

```
 idpers  wave
   <dbl> <dbl>
1      1  2008
2      1  2009
3      1  2012
4      2  2008
5      2  2011
6      4  2008
7      4  2009
8      4  2010
```

Comment: You can spare the `mutate` :) `df.short %>% group_by(idpers) %>% filter(any(wave <= 2008) & any(wave >= 2010))`

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table` you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.short)
df.short[, if (min(wave) <= 2008 && max(wave) >= 2010) .SD, by = idpers]

   idpers wave
1:      1 2008
2:      1 2009
3:      1 2012
4:      2 2008
5:      2 2011
6:      4 2008
7:      4 2009
8:      4 2010
```

Data

```
df.short <-  data.frame(
  idpers = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5),
  wave = c(2008,2009,2012,2008,2011,2005,2006,2007,2008,2008,2009,2010,2011)
)
```